# Uniform Convergence of convex functions implies convergence of derivatives in $L^1$?

Tags: derivatives, convex-analysis, uniform-convergence

It is known that if a sequence of continously differentiable, convex functions $f_n: [a,b] \longrightarrow [c,d]$ converges uniformly to a continously differentiable function $f: [a,b] \longrightarrow [c,d]$, that the derivatives $f_n^\prime$ converges pointwise to $f^\prime$. But the convergence doesn't need to be uniformly, see

[Convex functions and uniform convergence of derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290710/convex-functions-and-uniform-convergence-of-derivatives)

Does the convergence of $f_n^\prime$ to $f^\prime$ hold in the $L^1$-sense?